# Standard parameters for ruled surface

Tags: differential-geometry

There is this "trivial" Lemma that states
for a given ruled surface $x(t,v)=\alpha(t)+vw(t)$ there exists a reparametrization and redefinition such that

a) $|w(t)|=1 $

b) $|w'(t)|=1 $

c) $\left<\alpha'(t),w'(t)\right>=0$

My approach this far is:
Defining $\gamma(t):=\frac{w(t)}{|w(t)|}$, so a) holds.
Choosing an arc length parametrization also gives b).
Now I try to find a curve such that $\left<\alpha'(t),w'(t)\right>=0$

So let $y(t)=\beta(t)+u(t)\gamma(t)$
Taking the derivative gives

$y'(t)=\beta'(t)+u'(t)\gamma(t)+u(t)\gamma'(t)$
this yields
$\left<y'(t),\gamma'(t)\right>=\left<\beta'(t),\gamma'(t)\right>+u'(t)\left<\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)\right>+u(t)\left<\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)\right>$
Now it follows that
$\left<y'(t),\gamma'(t)\right>=u'(t)\left<\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)\right>+u(t)\left<\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)\right>$ because $\left<\beta'(t),\gamma'(t)\right>=0$
This is how far I got.
I am trying to get a formula for $u(t)$. But this needs either $\left<\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)\right>$ or $\left<\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)\right>$ to vanish.

Comment: Didn't read your calculations carefully, but $\gamma(t)$ is a unit vector for each $t$, which gives one of your final conditions. <> On the subject of readability, you might consider putting `$\newcommand{\brak}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}$` at the start of your post and coding inner products as, e.g., `$\brak{\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t)}$`. TeX and MathJaX space inequality signs as binary relations, making them hard to read when used as delimiters.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang why should $\gamma(t)$ being a unit vector imply this?

Comment: Arguably the most basic idiom of differential geometry concerns the derivative of a function of constant magnitude: What is $\gamma(t) \cdot \gamma(t)$, and what happens when you differentiate with respect to $t$? (Just asking rhetorically, no need to respond.)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want the second condition to be $|\alpha'(t)|=1$? Your $\alpha$ is the base curve, which should be a regular curve and could easily be reparametrized by arclength. But your $w$ is the directrix, which might well be a constant function of $t$, at least on some subinterval.